# It's possible to make a source code 32 or 64 bit only?

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, portability

As my understanding, I can compile my C code into 32bit binary or 64bit easily, but, some open source projects sais "*We don't support 32bit CPU*", so why? **what makes the code source 64bit only?**

I already checked many topics, questions & responses, but all are related to the OS, CPU, and the compiled binary files. While my question is related to the code source itself.

Comment: The obvious one is depending on pointer size for some strange reason. More likely they mean they don't build and test it on 32

Comment: @pm100 I see, so you mean their source code can be built in 32-bit mode, but they just prefer to no do it. So, the answer to my question basically all code sources can be safely build in 32/64 bit?

Comment: Here you go: https://godbolt.org/z/68YcW9Ga8

Comment: A relevant term here is "portability", which covers more than just 32 bit vs 64 bit, but also things like Linux vs Windows, x86_64 vs ARM64, clang vs gcc, etc. Here's an article that might provide some introductory reading: https://blog.bytellect.com/software-development/c/what-do-we-mean-by-portability-of-c-language-source-code/

Comment: Not only can pointer size change but native integer size can change too depending on what they compiled for. If their code doesn’t use fixed width integers it can change the behaviour of the program.

Comment: @SafelyFast Or vice versa... If a program does use fixed integer types in some cases it will render the program non-portable, while not using them will be portable. Such as in `uint32_t address = (uint32_t)&variable` vs `uintptr_t address = (uintptr_t)&variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction sets of CPUs will vary, and the instructions available will vary depending on the mode it's running in. The program might rely on larger integers provided in 64-bit mode, or it might have assembler that uses 64-bit instructions.

The different modes of operation also have different memory models. For example, a 32-bit Windows program can address 4 GiB of memory (a huge chunk of which it can't even use). On the other hand, a 64-bit Windows program can access virtually unlimited memory.

Comment: I see, so the two reasons are if the code uses 64-bit instructions under inline assembly, and the other one is if the program needs huge memory like a 3D modeling software or a video game. Got it.

Comment: Honestly, it's very easy to need more than 2 GiB.

Comment: Strange, There is Chromium 32bit version, and Office 365 32Bit also, while for example battlefield 2042 is totally 64Bit only, and Regard3D is also 64bit only. But I got my answer, Thank you =)

Comment: Let's look at a Chromium. Maybe it will crash it you open too many windows. Or maybe it has many processes instead. Or maybe there's a way to access extra memory, but it requires more effort and has a performance impact. My Firefox process is currently using over  5.5 GiB.

Comment: Although often related, processor width and memory addressing are separate parameters.  "source code 32 or 64 bit" may refer to one (likely the CPU width) or both.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Re "*processor width and memory addressing are separate parameters*", Yes. If you check, you'll see that the answer ties memory addressing to the "mode of operation [of the CPU]" rather than to the CPU itself.